# File name from $_FILES not playing nicely with apostrophes

Tags: php, file-upload

I am working on an image upload flow and am running into a weird issue after testing it.  We're trying to test it using the following file name:

```
1234567890-=!@#$%^&()_+qwertyuiop[]{}asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.png
```

After the form posts and I look at it in the $_FILES object, the name I get back is:

```
zxcvbnm,..png
```

(The two dots are not typos)

Upon looking into this, I've heard that it might have something to do with magic quotes.  I've tried turning them off and have had no success with it.  Any ideas?  Also, code below...

```
$size = sizeof($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
    $file_path = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $file_error = $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
    ...
```

The $file_name variable is what is getting trimmed.   Thoughts?

Comment: And you are doing a manual post in the browser, picking in the explorer a file with that "name"?

Comment: @JoopEggen you can create files with that name, and it is a good thing to do for detecting problems with non-usual characters. In my tests, I usually try to register usernames like that, to see if something (usually incorporated from some lib) accepts it fine or instead everything goes to hell.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós yes I was positively surprised that such a test was thought of. I asked whether it indeed was done manually, as an _automated_ test might be doing it wrong. That duplication of the `.` is baffling. - It looks like a URL rewriting.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why the period was being duplicated.  But it is fixed now.  Very strange.  Check the answer I marked -_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `addslashes` function on the name:
http://php.net/addslashes